# Data type and Operator type Errors

Tags: sql-server

i am following [learn sql the hard way tutorial](http://sql.learncodethehardway.org/), in tutorial tutor suggest to use sqllite 3 but im using MSSQL 2008 and i have a problem, tutor ask from me to find something using AND or OR operators, her is the query i wrote;

```
select * from pet where name like 'Flu%' and age = 1000
```

but i receive:

> Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Line 13 Operand type clash: text is
>   incompatible with smallint

i try this one

```
select * from pet where name like 'Flu%' and age = '1000'
```

i receive :

> Msg 402, Level 16, State 1, Line 13 The data types text and varchar
>   are incompatible in the equal to operator.

and when i convert age to varchar it works;

```
select * from pet where name like 'Flu%' and convert (varchar, age) = 1000
select * from pet where name like 'Flu%' and convert (varchar, age) = '1000'
```

it returns the correct answer

Here is the table design (as tutor wants);
id=int, name=text, breed=text, age=text, dead=int

why it doesnt work before converting to varchar?

Looking forward to your reply.

Kinds.

Comment: Not part of *this* problem, but likely to lead to others: [don't specify varchar without length](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got problem because sqllite and sql server datatype are different.

In the specific, you use a text datatype. This is bad, in sql server, for many reasons:

- Text will be removed in future versions of sql server: https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/ms187993.aspx
- You cannot compare with the equal operator
- Always choose appropriate data type. Store a number in a text field will lead you to problems.

So, I suggest you to build your table with appropriate datatypes. In your case name must be a varchar and age an integer (if it is ok).

Also you must not learn starting on a book for a specific rdbms and use another one, or you will get a lot of problems like this.